# How do i repackage .deb files to ubuntu snappy(snapcraft)

Tags: ubuntu, deb, snapcraft, xwiki, snap

I wanted to repackage .deb files specifically [XWiki .deb file install](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Installation/InstallationViaAPT/)  to a ubuntu snappy file.
since I lack knowledge on building snaps what methods do you suggest I use. would it be better to build XWiki from the source in snappy or repackage the .deb file into snappy. And also which one would be easy to maintain.
I also looked it up [similar question](https://up%20https://askubuntu.com/questions/635691/how-do-i-repackage-a-deb-for-ubuntu-snappy) here but since most documentation was removed by ubuntu it was difficult.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir tmp
```

unpack package

```
dpkg-deb -R package deb tmp
```

modify content of extracted content and
build new package

```
dpkg-deb -b tmp new.deb
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?